# VB.NET to English - What is this line of code supposed to do?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, vb.net-2010

Hi please could some interpret the following line of code into English?

```
"foo".TrimEnd(New Char(0  - 1) {})
```

I know what TrimEnd will do but not the Char bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you posted is quite meaningless in the context posted so was this manipulated from some code you found or a made up example?

To answer your question:

- `TrimEnd` removes characters from the end of a string
- `New Char(x)` creates an array of characters to be removed, `x` specifies the size of the array
- `0-1` specifies the upper bound of the array is `-1` - this doesn't make much sense as the array starts at `0` and ends at `-1`
- `{}` initialises the character array

Comment: I've copied and pasted it from the Reflector tool.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a NOOP because `TrimEnd()` is passed an empty array. This code will check if "o" (last character of "foo") is in the empty array, which it is not, and return "foo".

Comment: Are you sure about the last part? Checking if "o" is in empty array? TrimEnd is used to remove trailing white space...

Comment: The default behavior is to remove trailing white space. However you are passing in a char array. This changes the behavior to remove all trailing characters that are in the char array. However you are actually passing in an empty array, which is why it's a NOOP.